# Creating a database using jQuery mobile

Tags: database, jquery-mobile

I am wondering what is the best way to create a database using jQuery mobile for cross platform mobile devices.  I am making an app to where you create a time sheet for a week and save it.  I am thinking I will have to create sub databases inside another but right now I am not sure how to create a database.  I heard using php is a good...

Any help would be great. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What you want will probably best achieved by using a webservice. That way your jquery Mobile will communicate to your remote database that will store the data.

Check out [Adding a database to jquery mobile site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246380/adding-a-database-to-jquery-mobile-site)

Answer (score 0):

How about using with SQLite at modern browser?